# Criar array e contar valores

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional, array-associativo

Estou com uma mega dificuldade de desenhar um `array` em `PHP` com os seguintes dados que vem de um objeto `JSON`, não, não vem de uma consulta SQL em banco de dados.

Exemplo do `JSON`:

```
[
{
    "data": {
        "ID": "349",
        "user_login": "###",
        "user_pass": "###",
        "user_nicename": "###",
        "user_email": "###",
        "user_url": "",
        "source": "Google",
        "user_registered": "2018-03-22 12:46:35",
        "user_activation_key": "",
        "user_status": "0",
        "display_name": "Antonio Carlos Braga"
    },
    "ID": 349,
    "caps": {
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "cap_key": "gc_capabilities",
    "roles": [
        "subscriber"
    ],
    "allcaps": {
        "read": true,
        "level_0": true,
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "filter": null
},
{
    "data": {
        "ID": "292",
        "user_login": "###",
        "user_pass": "###",
        "user_nicename": "###",
        "user_email": "###",
        "user_url": "",
        "source": "Google",
        "user_registered": "2018-03-21 02:19:11",
        "user_activation_key": "",
        "user_status": "0",
        "display_name": "Adriana Cristina Alves da Silva"
    },
    "ID": 292,
    "caps": {
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "cap_key": "gc_capabilities",
    "roles": [
        "subscriber"
    ],
    "allcaps": {
        "read": true,
        "level_0": true,
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "filter": null
},
{
    "data": {
        "ID": "196",
        "user_login": "###",
        "user_pass": "###",
        "user_nicename": "###",
        "user_email": "###",
        "user_url": "",
        "source": "Facebook",
        "user_registered": "2018-03-20 14:28:58",
        "user_activation_key": "",
        "user_status": "0",
        "display_name": "Adriana Fernandes de oliveira"
    },
    "ID": 196,
    "caps": {
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "cap_key": "gc_capabilities",
    "roles": [
        "subscriber"
    ],
    "allcaps": {
        "read": true,
        "level_0": true,
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "filter": null
},
{
    "data": {
        "ID": "286",
        "user_login": "###",
        "user_pass": "###",
        "user_nicename": "###",
        "user_email": "###",
        "user_url": "",
        "source": "Google",
        "user_registered": "2018-03-21 01:19:53",
        "user_activation_key": "",
        "user_status": "0",
        "display_name": "Alexandre Ramos de Campos"
    },
    "ID": 286,
    "caps": {
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "cap_key": "gc_capabilities",
    "roles": [
        "subscriber"
    ],
    "allcaps": {
        "read": true,
        "level_0": true,
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "filter": null
},
{
    "data": {
        "ID": "225",
        "user_login": "###",
        "user_pass": "###",
        "user_nicename": "###",
        "user_email": "###",
        "user_url": "",
        "source": "Google",
        "user_registered": "2018-03-20 17:55:09",
        "user_activation_key": "",
        "user_status": "0",
        "display_name": "Alex miguins de lima"
    },
    "ID": 225,
    "caps": {
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "cap_key": "gc_capabilities",
    "roles": [
        "subscriber"
    ],
    "allcaps": {
        "read": true,
        "level_0": true,
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "filter": null
},
{
    "data": {
        "ID": "318",
        "user_login": "###",
        "user_pass": "###",
        "user_nicename": "###",
        "user_email": "###",
        "user_url": "",
        "source": "Google",
        "user_registered": "2018-03-21 14:35:38",
        "user_activation_key": "",
        "user_status": "0",
        "display_name": "Alexandra Alves Ferreira"
    },
    "ID": 318,
    "caps": {
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "cap_key": "gc_capabilities",
    "roles": [
        "subscriber"
    ],
    "allcaps": {
        "read": true,
        "level_0": true,
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "filter": null
},
{
    "data": {
        "ID": "188",
        "user_login": "###",
        "user_pass": "###",
        "user_nicename": "###",
        "user_email": "###",
        "user_url": "",
        "source": "Google",
        "user_registered": "2018-03-20 13:21:28",
        "user_activation_key": "",
        "user_status": "0",
        "display_name": "Analucia c g pedreira"
    },
    "ID": 188,
    "caps": {
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "cap_key": "gc_capabilities",
    "roles": [
        "subscriber"
    ],
    "allcaps": {
        "read": true,
        "level_0": true,
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "filter": null
},
{
    "data": {
        "ID": "216",
        "user_login": "###",
        "user_pass": "###",
        "user_nicename": "###",
        "user_email": "###",
        "user_url": "",
        "source": "Facebook",
        "user_registered": "2018-03-20 16:56:12",
        "user_activation_key": "",
        "user_status": "0",
        "display_name": "ANDREZA AP TOLEDO"
    },
    "ID": 216,
    "caps": {
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "cap_key": "gc_capabilities",
    "roles": [
        "subscriber"
    ],
    "allcaps": {
        "read": true,
        "level_0": true,
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "filter": null
},
{
    "data": {
        "ID": "299",
        "user_login": "###",
        "user_pass": "###",
        "user_nicename": "###",
        "user_email": "###",
        "user_url": "",
        "source": "Google",
        "user_registered": "2018-03-21 05:39:16",
        "user_activation_key": "",
        "user_status": "0",
        "display_name": "angela maria de queiroz"
    },
    "ID": 299,
    "caps": {
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "cap_key": "gc_capabilities",
    "roles": [
        "subscriber"
    ],
    "allcaps": {
        "read": true,
        "level_0": true,
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "filter": null
},
{
    "data": {
        "ID": "291",
        "user_login": "###",
        "user_pass": "###",
        "user_nicename": "###",
        "user_email": "###",
        "user_url": "",
        "source": "Google",
        "user_registered": "2018-03-21 02:15:56",
        "user_activation_key": "",
        "user_status": "0",
        "display_name": "Angelica dos Santos Marques"
    },
    "ID": 291,
    "caps": {
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "cap_key": "gc_capabilities",
    "roles": [
        "subscriber"
    ],
    "allcaps": {
        "read": true,
        "level_0": true,
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "filter": null
},
{
    "data": {
        "ID": "224",
        "user_login": "###",
        "user_pass": "###",
        "user_nicename": "###",
        "user_email": "###",
        "user_url": "",
        "user_registered": "2018-03-20 17:47:14",
        "user_activation_key": "",
        "user_status": "0",
        "display_name": "Adilson Nicanor de Assis"
    },
    "ID": 224,
    "caps": {
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "cap_key": "gc_capabilities",
    "roles": [
        "subscriber"
    ],
    "allcaps": {
        "read": true,
        "level_0": true,
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "filter": null
},
{
    "data": {
        "ID": "190",
        "user_login": "###",
        "user_pass": "###",
        "user_nicename": "###",
        "user_email": "###",
        "user_url": "",
        "source": "Facebook",
        "user_registered": "2018-03-20 13:39:58",
        "user_activation_key": "",
        "user_status": "0",
        "display_name": "António Carlos Bomfim Barros"
    },
    "ID": 190,
    "caps": {
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "cap_key": "gc_capabilities",
    "roles": [
        "subscriber"
    ],
    "allcaps": {
        "read": true,
        "level_0": true,
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "filter": null
},
{
    "data": {
        "ID": "359",
        "user_login": "###",
        "user_pass": "###",
        "user_nicename": "###",
        "user_email": "###",
        "user_url": "",
        "source": "Google",
        "user_registered": "2018-03-23 01:23:08",
        "user_activation_key": "",
        "user_status": "0",
        "display_name": "Marizete De Souza Lobato"
    },
    "ID": 359,
    "caps": {
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "cap_key": "gc_capabilities",
    "roles": [
        "subscriber"
    ],
    "allcaps": {
        "read": true,
        "level_0": true,
        "subscriber": true
    },
    "filter": null
}
]
```

Que traduzida em uma tabela seria:

```
| Fonte    | Data de cadastro |
|----------|------------------|
| Google   | 21/03/2018       |
| Google   | 22/03/2018       |
| Facebook | 21/03/2018       |
| Facebook | 22/03/2018       |
| Google   | 23/03/2018       |
| Facebook | 21/03/2018       |
| Google   | 21/03/2018       |
| Google   | 22/03/2018       |
```

Contando manualmente eu sei que no dia 21/03/2018 eu tive 2 cadastros do Google e 2 cadastros do Facebook, 22/03/2018 eu tive 1 cadastro do Google e 1 cadastro do Facebook, e assim por diante.

Eu gostaria de gerar um `array` que acredito ser associativo para gerar uma tabela assim depois de um `loop`:

```
| Fonte    | Data de cadastro | Total de cadastros |
|----------|------------------|--------------------|
| Google   | 21/03/2018       | 2                  |
| Facebook | 21/03/2018       | 2                  |
| Facebook | 22/03/2018       | 1                  |
| Facebook | 22/03/2018       | 1                  |
| Google   | 23/03/2018       | 1                  |
```

Também sei que essa soma pode ser obtida com uma função para somar os valores do `array` mas não consigo "desenhar" esse `array`.

Comment: Isso está no banco? tentou agrupar? tem como monstra como está constuido esse array?

Comment: Vem em um object JSON que posso facilmente em um loop e que desejo converter para array, mas não, não vem de uma consulta SQL

Comment: @DaniloP.daSilva você poderia colar esse JSON que você recebe? Pelo menos uma parte dele (se for mto grande) para vermos o formato.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta ;)

Comment: Seu `JSON` não é válido. Tem vírgula faltando e vírgula errada. Realmente é isso que está vindo do banco ? Erro para o `decode` nenhum ? Está colocando o "true" `$array = json_decode($json, true);` ?

Comment: Eu já havia limpado o JSON pra não ficar cheio de informação inútil da response. Esse é a response em JSON via Postman, não resultado em PHP com json_decode()

Comment: Você quer "agrupar" os registros iguais no array, com um contador... é isso ?

Comment: Isso, mas separados por data. Eu pensei em fazer isso através de um array pra poder gerar uma tabela no fim. Tipo, eu recebo em cada item do objeto JSON: id, email, nome, data de cadastro, fonte de trafego. E preciso compilar em uma tabela que no dia X eu recebi Y cadastros do Google, Z cadastros do Facebook.

Comment: Conforme esse JSON.. nem todos os registros possuem os dados que você quer.. Nem todos tem o Source especificado.

Comment: Esse JSON é só um exemplo, eu posso editar e colocar o source onde falta. O JSON é gigante, eu só editei o resultado final pra chegar proximo da lógica. Vou editar novamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não vou colar todo o JSON.. pq iria ficar um pouco exagerado, e o mesmo já se encontra na pergunta.. Segue um exemplo de código que separa os elementos por 'source' e conta o número de vezes que ocorreu em cada data 'Y-m-d'.

> O formato da data `format('Y-m-d')` pode ser alterado para `format('d/m/Y')` caso desejar.

```
$dados = json_decode([{...}]);
$result = [];
foreach($dados as $dado) {
  if(isset($dado->data->source)) { // Verifica se existe o 'source'
    $dataRegistro = (new DateTime($dado->data->user_registered))->format("Y-m-d");

    if(!isset($result[$dado->data->source])) { // Cria array no indice caso n exista.
      $result[$dado->data->source] = [];
    } 

    if(!isset($result[$dado->data->source][$dataRegistro])) { // Insere primeiro cadastro
      $result[$dado->data->source][$dataRegistro] = 1;
    } else {
      $result[$dado->data->source][$dataRegistro] += 1; // Adiciona cadastro existente..
    }
  }
}

print_r($result);
```

A saída desse código vai ser algo assim:

```
Array
(
    [Google] => Array
        (
            [2018-03-22] => 1
            [2018-03-21] => 1
        )

    [Facebook] => Array
        (
            [2018-03-20] => 1
        )

)
```

Para printar os valores de forma 'Tabular' você poderia fazer assim:

```
foreach($result as $k=>$v) {
  foreach($v as $data=>$ocorrencias) {
    echo $k . ' | ' . $data . ' | ' . $ocorrencias . "\n";
  }
}
```

O que resultaria em:

```
Google | 2018-03-22 | 1
Google | 2018-03-21 | 1
Facebook | 2018-03-20 | 1
```

Comment: Demorei a testar o código, mas é exatamente isso que precisava. Só encontrei uma dificuldade na parte do código que você usou `POO`, eu alterei e funcionou. Ao invés de `$result[$dado->data->source][$dataRegistro]` eu usei `$result[$dado['data']['ID']][$dataRegistro]` e consegui, antes o `print_r($result)` vinha em branco. Obrigado cara!